# Git stash reset version to previous. How do I get my work back?

Tags: git, git-stash

I am working with git for a college project and it has been a tricky learning curve.  Last night I was trying to upload my work into the main tree and I did first a 'git stash' in terminal and it seems to have reset my code to the previous version. I am a git novice. Is there a way that I can get my work back?

Heres what I put in to terminal and what it read out:

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 00b2935 undated with desktop(unfinished)
HEAD is now at 00b2935 undated with desktop(unfinished)
[  ][ darraghkenny ][][master=][ ~/projects/RosettaFoundation-new-design ]
$
```

Comment: git stash pop applies the top stashed element and removes it from the stack. git stash apply does the same, but leaves it in the stash stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can type

```
$ git stash list
```

to print out a list of all previously saved stashes.

Chronologically, you can fetch them back using

```
$ git stash apply stash@{0}
```

being the latest one, `stash@{1}` being the penultimate one, and `stash@{N}` for subsequent stashes

Comment: Thank you sircapsalot. That worked for me and I will research further into the stashing process. Also I will mark your answer correct when it allows.

Comment: If there are multiple entries in the stash, you can use `git stash show -p stash@{n}` for a preview of the nth entry without applying its content.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this command can do the work:

```
    git stash pop
```